# Fold / Collapse the except code section in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there any plugin or shortcut to hide all except code section in sublime text 2?

I need to fold all except section at a time , Not fold one section at a time.

Thanks~

[image]

Answer (score 202, accepted):

If you'll hover with the mouse over the line numbers you'll see arrows - clicking on any of them will fold/collapse the code

[image]

[image]

If you want to collapse/expand all - you can do so by going to edit->code folding and choose "fold all" or "unfold all":

[image]

Comment: but is can only fold one section at a time, I want to fold all except section :)

Comment: @poc in that case you can choose from the menu: `edit -> code folding -> fold/unfold all` - I'll add a screenshot in a min

Comment: If you don't have these then add `"fold_buttons": true` to the `Preferences -> Settings - User`.

Comment: Is there a shortcut for toggling the folding instead of requiring two different commands?

Comment: @Joe you can see the keyboard shortcuts in the last screenshot. These shortcuts are for Mac but I bet that Windows shows its shortcuts as well.

Comment: Is there a shortcut for the sidebar arrow folding? The arrow folding automatically defines code blocks which is very useful. However the menu hotkeys fold require you to select what you want to fold. I'm looking for a way of folding automatically designated segments (what the arrows show) without using the mouse.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to the other answers it is also possible to fold based on level as well. So for example looking at the default key bindings for fold.

[image: Subblime key bindings default]

Searching for fold key bindings.

[image: searching for fold key bindings in sublime]

So for example a foldall, or folding level 1 would be to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> followed by pressing the sequence <kbd>k</kbd> and then <kbd>1</kbd>:

[image]

Or folding level 2 would be to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> followed by pressing the sequence <kbd>k</kbd> and then  <kbd>2</kbd>:

[image]

Or unfolding all would be would be to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> followed by pressing the sequence <kbd>k</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd> or in my defaults I also seem to have it bound to the letter <kbd>j</kbd>:

[image]

## Warning.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> twice will remove a line or a count of lines.
But not really cause you can put them back one by one by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

Comment: Most precise answer! Thank you so much, saved my day :)

Answer (score 15):

One thing you can do is select the Except code bloc using a regular expression, for instance using `except(.|\n)*?raise.*` in your case. You can then select "Find all" in the search bar, then Edit->Code Folding -> Fold .
Windows shortcut : Ctrl-Shift-[
Mac shortcut: Cmd-Alt-[

All the Except bloc will then be collapsed.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but it still comes up high in search results and none of the answers quite do what the OP wanted.

1. select the code you *don't* want to be hidden
2. use "Selection" -> "Invert Selection" to select the code you *do* want to be hidden instead
3. use `ctrl + shift + [` or `Command + Option + ]` to collapse the selection(s)

This will leave you with just the code you originally had selected visible.

Answer (score 2):

Fold and UnFold function or class base only for MAC:

```
 * Fold: command + K, command + 1
 * UnFold: command + K, command + J
```